# Count the number in data array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like below. In my real case, it has thousands of objects.

```
var data = [
  {type:'A',time:'2009'},
  {type:'A',time:'2009'},
  {type:'A',time:'2009'},
  {type:'A',time:'2009'},
  {type:'B',time:'2009'},
  {type:'B',time:'2009'},
  {type:'B',time:'2009'},
  {type:'C',time:'2009'}, 

  {type:'A',time:'2014'},
  {type:'A',time:'2014'},
  {type:'B',time:'2014'},
  {type:'B',time:'2014'},
  {type:'B',time:'2014'},
  {type:'B',time:'2014'},
  {type:'C',time:'2014'},
  {type:'C',time:'2014'}
];
var validTime = ['2009', '2014'];
var typeArr = ['A','B','C'];
```

I want to convert the '`data`' array to the '`newData`' which calculates the count of every type in each year.

```
var newData = [
  {time:'2009', A:4, B:3, C:1},
  {time:'2014', A:2, B:3, C:2}
]
```

This is what I have done so far. I don't know what to do in the next step. I think I am going far away from the right approach. I usually use R for processing the data and just pick up javascript for a couple of weeks. Can anyone guide me how to do it or any web resources with similar problem would be very helpful!!Thanks!

And appreciate if you could add some comments in your answer!

```
var arr1 = [];
for (i = 0; i < validTime.length; i++) {
    for (s = 0; s < typeArr.length; s++) {
            var count = 0;
            for (j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
                if (data[j]['time'] == validTime[i] && data[j]['type'] == typeArr[s]){
                            count++;                                                        
                        }
                    }
                            arr1.push({
                            'type': typeArr[s],
                            'x': validTime[i],
                            'y': count                                              
                            });
                }
            };
console.log(arr1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```js
var data = [
  { type:'A', time: '2009' },
  { type:'A', time: '2009' },
  { type:'A', time: '2009' },
  { type:'A', time: '2009' },
  { type:'B', time: '2009' },
  { type:'B', time: '2009' },
  { type:'B', time: '2009' },
  { type:'C', time: '2009' },

  { type:'A', time: '2014' },
  { type:'A', time: '2014' },
  { type:'B', time: '2014' },
  { type:'B', time: '2014' },
  { type:'B', time: '2014' },
  { type:'B', time: '2014' },
  { type:'C', time: '2014' },
  { type:'C', time: '2014' }
];

var newData = { };
data.forEach(function(item) {
  
  // if we don't already have a record for this time, create one
  if (!newData[item.time]) {
    newData[item.time] = { };
  }
  
  // add 1 to the current value of this type for the given time      
  newData[item.time][item.type] = (newData[item.time][item.type] || 0) + 1;
});

document.writeln('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(newData, null, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

https://linqjs.codeplex.com/ Use this library, so you don't have to write your own methods.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the easy way, can be optimized if need be (particularly if you can guarantee the type order as in your example)

```
var newData = [];

for (var t = 0; t < validTime.length; t++) {
  var acount = 0, bcount = 0, ccount = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].time === validTime[t]) {
      switch (data[i].type) {
        case 'A':
          acount++;
          break;
        case 'B':
          bcount++;
          break;
        case 'C':
          ccount++;
          break;
      }
    }
  }
  newData.push({time: validTime[t], A: acount, B: bcount, C: ccount});
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fL08n0m7/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [
  {type:'A',time:'2009'},
  {type:'A',time:'2009'},
  {type:'A',time:'2009'},
  {type:'A',time:'2009'},
  {type:'B',time:'2009'},
  {type:'B',time:'2009'},
  {type:'B',time:'2009'},
  {type:'C',time:'2009'}, 

  {type:'A',time:'2014'},
  {type:'A',time:'2014'},
  {type:'B',time:'2014'},
  {type:'B',time:'2014'},
  {type:'B',time:'2014'},
  {type:'B',time:'2014'},
  {type:'C',time:'2014'},
  {type:'C',time:'2014'}
];

var validTime = ['2009', '2014'];
var typeArr = ['A','B','C'];

// store the result inn object
var out = data.reduce(function (hash, item) {
    if (validTime.indexOf(item.time) >= 0) {
    hash[item.time] = hash[item.time] || {};
    if (typeArr.indexOf(item.type) >= 0) {
        hash[item.time][item.type] = hash[item.time][item.type] || 0;
    }
    hash[item.time][item.type] += 1;
  }
  return hash;
}, {});

// convert result to array
var value, type, time, arr = [], item;
for (time in out) {
    value = out[time];
    item = {
        time: time
    };
    for (type in value) {
       item[type] = value[type];
    }
    arr.push(item);
}

console.log(arr); // this is expected result (array)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will organize what you want into the array's you're looking for.  Using two small loops will be much faster than the way you're tackling it.

```
var data = [

{type:'A',time:'2009'},
  {type:'A',time:'2009'},
  {type:'A',time:'2009'},
  {type:'A',time:'2009'},
  {type:'B',time:'2009'},
  {type:'B',time:'2009'},
  {type:'B',time:'2009'},
  {type:'C',time:'2009'}, 

  {type:'A',time:'2014'},
  {type:'A',time:'2014'},
  {type:'B',time:'2014'},
  {type:'B',time:'2014'},
  {type:'B',time:'2014'},
  {type:'B',time:'2014'},
  {type:'C',time:'2014'},
  {type:'C',time:'2014'}
];
var validTime = ['2009', '2014'];
var typeArr = ['A','B','C'];
var tempData = {}, newData = [];
var item;

for(var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
    item = data[i];
  if(!tempData[item.time]) {
    tempData[item.time] = {};
  }

  tempData[item.time][item.type] = (tempData[item.time][item.type] || 0) + 1;
}

$.each(tempData, function(index, item) {
  newData.push($.extend(item, {time: index}));
});

console.log(newData);
```

JS Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7bd1Lvb2/

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `for` loop , `for..in` loops. The resulting object `res` should contain properties having name of object `type`; each property should contain two arrays, the first array should be the filtered results of the `type`,  the second array should contain properties of `time` for each filtered result, that is, `2009` and `2014`

```js
var data = [
  {type:'A',time:'2009'},
  {type:'A',time:'2009'},
  {type:'A',time:'2009'},
  {type:'A',time:'2009'},
  {type:'B',time:'2009'},
  {type:'B',time:'2009'},
  {type:'B',time:'2009'},
  {type:'C',time:'2009'}, 
  {type:'A',time:'2014'},
  {type:'A',time:'2014'},
  {type:'B',time:'2014'},
  {type:'B',time:'2014'},
  {type:'B',time:'2014'},
  {type:'B',time:'2014'},
  {type:'C',time:'2014'},
  {type:'C',time:'2014'}
];

for (var i = 0, res = {}; i < data.length; i++) {
  if (res[data[i].type] === undefined) {
    if (!Array.isArray(res[data[i].type])) {
      res[data[i].type] = [];
      res[data[i].type].push(data[i])
    } else {
      res[data[i].type].push(data[i])
    }
  } else {
    res[data[i].type].push(data[i])
  }
}

for (var prop in res) {
  res[prop] = [res[prop], {2009:[], 2014:[]}];
  res[prop].forEach(function(value) {
    for (var p in res[prop][1]) {
      res[prop][1][p] = res[prop][0].filter(function(v) {
        return v["time"] === p
      })
    }
  })
}

document.querySelector("pre").textContent = JSON.stringify(res, null, 2)
```

```html
<pre>

</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got a working answer. This was a great exercise for me.

The code you currently have returns an array of 6 objects.

```
{"type":"A","x":"2009","y":4}
{"type":"B","x":"2009","y":3}
{"type":"C","x":"2009","y":1}
{"type":"A","x":"2014","y":2}
{"type":"B","x":"2014","y":4}
{"type":"C","x":"2014","y":2}
```

as viewed from https://jsfiddle.net/aa15y7n0/

The results you desire is an array with one object per string in validTime array. Each of these objects have the labels found in typeArr.

I created the result array like so:

```
var arr2 = [];
//start by creating the array with the corect number of objects (2)
for(var i = 0; i < validTime.length; i++) {
    arr2.push({
  'time': validTime[i]
  });
}
//append onto those two objects the typeArr objects.
for(var i=0;i<arr2.length;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<typeArr.length;j++){
    var thisObj = arr2[i];
    var thisProp = typeArr[j];
    thisObj[thisProp] = 0;
  }
}
//modify the values to increase the counters
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
  for(var j=0;j<arr2.length;j++){
    if(data[i].time == arr2[j].time){
        //increase arr2[j].type count by 1.
      var thisDataObjType = data[i].type;
      arr2[j][thisDataObjType] += 1;
    }
  }
}
```

You can see the results at https://jsfiddle.net/aa15y7n0/1/